# POST transmission of file fails with UWP

Tags: c#, php, .net, visual-studio, uwp

### Trouble

I'd like to send the value and file POST from the UWP application (C #) to the API created in PHP, but it seems that the file can not be sent.

- param1 is StringValue.
- param2 is UploadFile.

#### Excerpt of sample.php

```
if($_FILES['param2'])
```

#### UWP (Failed. $_FILES['param2'] false)

```
private async Task PostSample()
{
    const string POST_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/sample.php";

    var multi = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();

    var param1 = new HttpStringContent("foo");
    multi.Add(param1, "param1");

    byte[] values = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };
    var param2 = new HttpStreamContent(new MemoryStream(values).AsInputStream());
    param2.Headers.ContentDisposition = new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "param2",
        FileName = "piyo.dat"
    };
    multi.Add(param2);

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var res = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(POST_URL), multi);

    var diag = new MessageDialog(res.ToString());
    await diag.ShowAsync();
}
```

---

### What I tried

#### External Tool

In the Advanced REST Client by GoogleChrome, it succeeded

#### Windows Forms (Successed)

It succeeded on Windows Forms.

```
private async Task PostSample()
{
    const string POST_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/sample.php";

    var multi = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    var param1 = new StringContent("foo");
    multi.Add(param1, "param1");

    byte[] values = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };
    var param2 = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(values));
    param2.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "param2",
        FileName = "piyo.dat"
    };
    multi.Add(param2);

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var res = await client.PostAsync(POST_URL, multi);
    MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
}
```

### Guess

Is my UWP code incorrect or can not be sent on UWP?

Thank you.

Comment: The environment is Windows 10 (14393) + 64 bit + .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: What error or exception does the project throw?